# Get id attribute value from element - Blazor

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I have a standard Blazor app where I dynamically create a table and want to be able to identify each table entry by a unique identifier.

Currently I have each `<td>` element be assigned the counter value in my `for` loop like so:

```
for (var i=0; i < 7; i++)
{
  <td id=@i @onlick="() => SelectEntry()">@i</td>
}
```

I want to be able to pass the id value to the `onclick` method so I know which table entry was clicked on but am unsure how.

Comment: You can help Blazor with `@key='@i'` instead of `id='@i'`

Answer (score 1):

It is important that you assign your value from `i` to a new variable, otherwise you would always pass the last value of i into the function.

What you can do would be this:

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  var myValue = i;
  <td id="@myValue" @onlick="() => SelectEntry(myValue)">@myValue</td>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You current method will not produce unique ids: you assign the same `id` to cells in each row.

Here's some code that will make each cell unique.  It uses a guid to identify the table and then `Rx:Cx` to identify the cell.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<table class="table">
    @for (var row = 1; row < 10; row++)
    {
        <tr>
            @for (var col = 1; col < 5; col++)
            {
                var id = $"R{row}:C{col}";
                var uid = $"{_tableId}-R{row}:C{col}";
                <td class="@this.CellCss(uid)" id="@uid" @onclick="() => this.OnCellSelected(uid)">@id</td>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>Selected Cell: @_selectedCell</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private string? _selectedCell;

    private string _tableId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    private string CellCss(string value)
        => value.Equals(_selectedCell)
            ? "bg-dark text-white"
            : "";

    private void OnCellSelected(string? value)
        => _selectedCell = value;
}
```

[image]